# How to listen a specific key on value change with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

is there a way to listen value change for specific key? With below given code I get a window alert eachtime there is a change in local storage it works well but what i am looking for to add a event listener just for key : "Data".

```
<body>
  <button onClick="setData1()">Set 1</button>
  <button onClick="setData2()">Set 2</button>
<button onClick="clearData()">Clear</button>
</body>
</html>
<script>
window.addEventListener('storage', function(e) {  
alert('Woohoo, someone changed my localstorage!');
});

function setData1(){
  console.log('SET');
  localStorage.setItem('Data', '1');
}

function setData2(){
  console.log('SET');
  localStorage.setItem('Data', '2');
}

function clearData(){
  console.log('CLEAR');
  localStorage.clear()
}

</script>
```

https://codepen.io/rahman23/pen/KKdyGOw

Answer (score 8):

The [`storage` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageEvent) tells you what key changed via its `key` property, so you can use that to decide whether to do your `alert`:

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function(e) {  
    if (e.key === "Data") {
        alert('Woohoo, someone changed my localstorage!');
    }
});
```

Note that the event will only be fired if the value is changed in a *different* window, not the same window. (I assume you know this, as you said you were getting the `alert`.) If you ran your page in two tabs, for instance, clicking your buttons in one tab would cause the event in the other, but not in the one where you clicked the button.

In a comment you said you wanted to get notifications from changes made by the same window. The only way to do that is to write a wrapper function for `setItem` and call your handler directly, something like this:

```
function storageChanged({key, oldValue, newValue}) {
    if (key === "Data") {
        const isNew = oldValue === null && newValue !== null;
        console.log(`Data event, new value = "${newValue}". First time? ${isNew ? "Yes" : "No"}`);
    }
}

window.addEventListener('storage', storageChanged);

function setLocalStorage(key, newValue) {
    newValue = String(newValue);
    const oldValue = localStorage.getItem(key);
    localStorage.setItem(key, newValue);
    storageChanged({
        key,
        oldValue,
        newValue,
        storageArea: localStorage,
        url: window.location.url
    });
}

function clearLocalStorage() {
    localStorage.clear();
    storageChanged({
        key: null,
        oldValue: null,
        newValue: null,
        storageArea: localStorage,
        url: window.location.url
    });
}
```

If you change your button handlers to use those functions, you get notifications both for changes made in the window and for changes made in other windows.

[Live example on JSBin](https://output.jsbin.com/noloyeraye/1) (which is one of the few that lets us use local storage).

Comment: Thanks for answer, is there a way to detect if "Data" key inserted for the first time in localstorage?

Comment: I tried with e.key but it gives me alert if i manually change the Data value with Chrome dev tool if I use set1 and set2 buttons to change the value it gives no alert.

Comment: Your example is not working. According to MDN the storage event is only fired if it "has been modified in the context of another document."

Comment: @user1953051 - Please read the linked page. The `oldValue` property will be `null` the first time the key is used. About changing it with the buttons in your page, the event only fires when the value is changed by a *different* window, not by the *same* window. The expectation is if you're changing it in the same window, you'll know that. The event is for when it's changed elsewhere.

Comment: @Kalimah - I didn't say the event would fire for changes in the same window. I assumed the OP knew that as they were getting the alert. But given their comment above, apparently not.

Comment: you could also add another if statement to check if its the first time they add something to that storage with the given key `if(!localStorage.getItem(e.key)){ //do something }`

Comment: Is there a way to fire it if it has been modified on same page?

Comment: @user1953051 - No. Again, the assumption is you only want notifications from *other* code. If you want to do something every time the value changes, whether in code on the page or in other windows, write a wrapper function for `setItem` that sets the item and calls your handler.

Comment: @Ifaruki - My understanding of the question was that they wanted to know in the handler, not when doing `setItem` (Also: That check isn't reliable, you can store `""`, which is falsy. You need explicitly to check for `null`.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder. I meant to post my comment on the question. I posted on your answer by mistake.